# Пересечение отрезков времени

Tags: алгоритм, дата, mysql

MYSQL есть таблица заказов типа:
**id** ind
**date_start** timestamp
**date_end** timestamp
**room_id** int

она всячески там заполнена заказами с датами, нужно получить ответ типа:
room_id, count(id) для промежутка времени filter_date_start, filter_date_end. Я в принципе понимаю, что задача достаточно тривиальная но у меня не хватает знаний sql для формирования данного списка. Как я понял надо учесть варианты вхождения дат.

Comment: SELECT roomid,COUNT( * ) 
FROM  `book` 
WHERE  `datestart` <= filter_date_end 
AND  `dateend` >=  filter_date_start
GROUP BY roomid

Comment: @binliz: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where date_start <= filter_date_end and date_end >= filter_date_start
```

?